# DotNetNuke Upgrade 4.9.2 - PermanentRedirect Failure

Tags: dotnetnuke, upgrade

When installing DNN 04.09.02 upgrade (from DNN 4.8.4) I receive System.IndexOutOfRangeException: PermanentRedirect error and cannot install the upgrade. How do I get around this so I can install the upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-posted the following from the thread provided by kitsune. [Source](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/threadid/289312/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

First try the following in your browser. Replace "www.yourdomain.com" with your domain:

http://www.yourdomain.com/install/install.aspx?mode=install

If that doesn't work (which it didn't for me) then try the following steps (copied from Chris on that thread).

To manually run the SQL portion of the upgrade you'll need to run each upgrade script between your version and 4.9.2.  I upgraded from 4.9.0 to 4.9.2 so I performed the following:

1. On the web server open the directory: \Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider
2. Determine which files need to be run.  Basically, all of the versions after your old version.  In my case I needed to run the files 04.09.00.SqlDataProvider, 04.09.01.SqlDataProvider and 04.09.02.SqlDataProvider.
3. Open the SQL files in a text editor and replace "{databaseOwner}" (usually with "dbo.") and "{objectQualifier}" (usually with "", but sometimes "DNN4" or some other object prefix)
4. Run those SQL files in version order using SQL Management Studio. 
   Assuming those scripts ran without an error then the site should be ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/threadid/289312/scope/posts/Default.aspx) might help you:

It looks like you have to update it manually... steps are described there.

Also check [this thread](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/postid/294390/scope/posts/Default.aspx), might be due to AD if AD is used.